# How would you go about implementing chat in django?

Tags: ajax, django, chat, server-push

**If you were to implement Chat (i.e. a real time text conversation) in Django how would you go about doing it ?**

My thoughts on it ( please do have mercy on the noob ) -
Create a table for storing archived messages and one for storing current messages.
And populate the current chat by querying the current messages table every 20 secs using javascript.  But this *feels* so wrong.
 There has to be a better way. I've heard something called as the push technology. How do I use it with django ?
P.S. My site is being shared hosted on dreamhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mainly concerned with the front end, look into comet.

As for the backend, you have a lot of different options.  A more straightforward one would be to store each chat message in the database for the given chat room.  Maybe a many to many relation between the chat room table and the chat message.

Other solutions include key value store databases that aren't built in to Django.  You could possibly push messages into a redis set, or store active chat room data in memcached.

Since this is on dreamhost, I would look into the database option.  The truth is that you have to store some data with each chat message.  Who made it, what time it was made, etc.  This will have to go into a table at some point in your environment.  Try to just make it work and then see if you can make it faster.

Comment: Upvote for "just make it work and then see if you can make it faster."

Answer (score 3):

Most web chat applications tend to use Comet Programming. Comet is not a real push technology, but more of a simulation of it. First off there are different implementation of comet, but generally pooling and ajax is used to repeatedly check the server to see if there is a message. Comet generally results in too many round trips, and therefore steps have been taken to find more suitable alternatives such as Bosh which simply keep the connection open. This could actually be considered real push as opposed to Comet. The wiki link below list alternatives but in generally I think Comet and Bosh are the most used methods for chat. You could possibly even used both methods together. Here are some links.

- [Django powered AJAX Chat](http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/django-powered-ajax-chat-part-1/)
- [Django and Comet](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-and-comet/)
- [Comet (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)